# Removing Div from mobile view

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, media-queries

I would like to remove my carousel from my mobile view. I have it working with my media query but that just make the div invisible but the images still load. Is there a way with jquery to completely delete the code when viewed in mobile width.

Comment: maybe `if($(window).width < x) { $(yourdiv).remove(); }`

Comment: jQuery [.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Comment: It may be a better approach to configure your carousel appropriately for mobile sizes and load smaller images.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be more useful for you to consider *adding* the carousel to ensure the images do not load on mobile devices.

Using something like: `$('.hidden').remove();` as in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z84bqeuL/) will still load the image because the DOM loads prior to the javascript. You can inspect the network traffic to confirm.

Instead, you can build your image dynamically, as [so](https://jsfiddle.net/vgp2wsdL/):

```
var img = $('<img class="hidden"></img>');
img.attr('src','http://placehold.it/350x150');
img.appendTo('#container');
```

Combine that with your necessary if checks, and you'll ensure that the image doesn't load unless it meets your specified criteria.